# rs.reconfig not works, it still shows the original config

Tags: mongodb

I typed the following commands in mongo console

But it didn't work

```
config = {"_id" : "vvtk_dqa",
"members" : [
    {"_id": 1, "host": "192.168.14.7"},
    {"_id": 2, "host": "223.137.30.107"}    
]
}


rs.reconfig(config, {force: true});
```

returned message

```
{
    "msg" : "will try this config momentarily, try running rs.conf() again in a few seconds",
    "ok" : 1
}
```

rs.conf() still shows the original result.

> rs.conf()
>   {
>       "_id" : "vvtk_dqa",
>       "version" : 4,
>       "members" : [
>           {
>               "_id" : 1,
>               "host" : "172.19.16.109:27017"
>           },
>           {
>               "_id" : 2,
>               "host" : "172.19.16.104:27017"
>           },
>           {
>               "_id" : 3,
>               "host" : "192.168.14.7:27017"
>           }
>       ]
>   }

Comment: What's happening in the replica set? Can you post `rs.status()`? Is there anything in the logs?

Comment: Have the same issue and rs.status() shows the following: 
`{ "startupStatus" : 3, "info" : "run rs.initiate(...) if not yet done for the set","ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed (EMPTYCONFIG)"}`